# Can a Silverlight OOB App still be run from a Web Site

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-oob

Hi everybody at stackoverflow, I've created a small application which is designed and written in Silverlight 5 (vb). I chose to use the out of browser settings (oob)for the application because I did not want to use a whole page just for a small calculator application. My question is: can I still attach and run the oob application from a website online without a user ever having to  download it to be able to use it? What is the procedure for deployment to a server?  I'm assuming that once deployed to the server a link from the web page would enable running of the application? I'm a complete novice in this area so any advice would be much appreciated.
Kind regards 
Will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. OOB mode only adds some security permissions (and can be installed as desktop app), but it still will be downloaded from web source.

Comment: In the OOB settings it gives you the option to show the install menu. If I leave this option unchecked does this mean that any users do not have the option to download and install? What I want to avoid is for anyone to download the app. I just want to keep it online.

Comment: for sure, you can use oob mode without installing app. to client machine

Comment: Thanks for your help Dima, is deployment to a client web server done through Visual Studio i.e type in the web address and deploy an over the air install to the server?